# WooCommerce Coupon - how to echo it for an actual order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to echo a coupon code on certain location on the page that was used for order (if it was used at all).

I'm using this code:

```
if(function_exists('print_coupon_name')){
global $woocommerce; 
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();
echo "Coupon: " . $coupons;
}
```

I'm Getting this result:

```
Coupon: Array
```

Do I need to pull certain data from array? Is this code above really taking coupon data from actual order or do I need to preselect order somehow? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns either an empty array or an array of coupons names if exist.
you need to check if the returned array isn't empty and loop over it.

```
if(function_exists('print_coupon_name')){
   global $woocommerce; 
   $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
   $coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();
   if ( ! empty( $coupons ) ) {
      foreach ( $coupons as $coupon ) {
         echo "Coupon: " . $coupon;
      }
   }
}
```